# NHibernate correlated subquery using ICriteria

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria, correlated-subquery

I've been doing some work evaluating NHibernate for an upcoming project and am working through some use cases to see how it performs. I haven't yet been able to find a way to express the following query using the Criteri API.

Two fairly basic tables (cut down for the purpose of this example)

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonNo  INT,
    BirthDate DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE PersonDetails
(
    PersonNo  INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(30),
    Surname   VARCHAR(30)
)
```

And the query...

```
SELECT P.PersonNo, P.FirstName, P.Surname
FROM Persons P
JOIN PersonDetails PD
  ON PD.PersonNo = P.PersonNo
 AND EffDate =
    (
        SELECT MAX(EffDate)
        FROM PersonDetails
        WHERE PersonNo = PD.PersonNo
    )
WHERE P.PersonNo = 1
```

Basically, I am just trying to flatten the person master record and the latest person revision record into one object. I was able to do this easily enough using HQL but cannot get the correlated subquery to work.

Here's my attempt.

```
var pdSub = DetachedCriteria.For<PersonRevision>("pdSub")
    .SetProjection(
        Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.Max("EffDate").As("MaxEffDate"))
            .Add(Projections.Property("Person.PersonNo").As("PersonNo")) 
            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Person.PersonNo")))
    .Add(Expression.EqProperty("pdSub.Person.PersonNo", "p.PersonNo"));    

var p =
    session.CreateCriteria<Person>("p")                                                
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("p.PersonNo", 1))
        .Add(Subqueries.Eq("p.PersonNo", pdSub))
        .List();
```

The subquery pdSub already defines the relationship (by PersonNo) but the Subqueries class requires another relationship to be defined (e.g. Eq)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 6):

For the purposes of a demo I've added EffDate to both tables. Hopefully that matches your model and demonstrates this kind of join appropriately.

```
DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria
    .For<PersonDetails>("pd")
    .SetProjection(Projections.Max("pd.EffDate"))
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("pd.PersonId", "p.PersonId"));

IList results = Session
    .CreateCriteria(typeof(Person), "p")
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("p.PersonId").As("PersonId"))
        .Add(Projections.Property("p.EffDate").As("MaxEffDate")))
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("p.EffDate", subQuery))
    .List();
```

The SQL NHibernate is throwing at the server looks like this...

```
SELECT this_.PersonId as y0_, this_.EffDate as y1_ FROM Person this_ WHERE this_.EffDate = (SELECT max(this_0_.EffDate) as y0_ FROM PersonDetails this_0_ WHERE this_0_.PersonId = this_.PersonId)
```