# nhibernate selecting top record from 1:m relationship

Tags: nhibernate

Can someone please give me a hint on how to turn this SQL into the NHibernate equivalent?

```
select * 
from clients
left join clientOrders 
    on (clientOrders.clientId = clients.Id)
where clientOrders.DateCreated is null 
or clientOrders.DateCreated =(
    select MAX(DateCreated) 
    from clientOrders 
    where clientId=clients.Id
)
```

I can't figure out the last term in the where clause. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Also, here's a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010897/nhibernate-correlated-subquery-using-icriteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without more information about your mappings will be impossible to get the correct code, but it would be something like this:

**Assuming you have a collection of client orders in your client, named 'ClientOrders'**

```
//Create the criteria for objects of type 'Client'
ICriteria target = Session.CreateCriteria<Client>();

//create an alias for the client orders, to be able to add the restrictions                    
    target.CreateAlias("Orders", "ClientOrders", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

//Add the restrinctions using an 'Or' to allow any of this two conditions                    
    target.Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.IsNull("Orders.DateCreated"), Restrictions.Eq("Orders.DateCreated",
                        Session.CreateCriteria<DateTime>().SetProjection(Projections.Max("Orders.DateCreated")).UniqueResult<DateTime>())));

//Get the list of the clients        
    target.List<Client>();
```

Again, this should give you a hint only, because without having your mappings, it's impossible to know what you have in there. Hope it helps...

Comment: this looks a lot more like it. I'll give it a try, although I created  a view and used it in the mapping instead. Thanks Sergio for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try the `coalesce` function, its the analog of `nvl` function at SQL query. So, in your case the last term in the `WHERE` will look like this

```
coalesce(clientOrders.DateCreated, clientOrders.DateCreated=(select MAX(DateCreated) from clientOrders where clientId=clients.Id))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: not sure how to use this. I was expecting something like: criteria.Add(Restrictions.... since this is the equivalent for the where clause.